# Derivative of functions (variable raised to power variable) using partial derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

If x^x = y^y, then find dy/dx

The normal method is taking log both sides which gives

x.lnx= y.lny

differentiating both sides we get

x(1/x)+1.lnx= y(1/y)+1.lny(dy/dx)

therefore, dy/dx= 1+lnx/1+lny

**BUT** by using **partial derivative**,

f(x,y)=x^x-y^y

The ans comes out to be

dy/dx= -[x^x(lnx+1)]/-[y^y(lny+1)]

Can someone plz help..

Comment: In your last equation use $x^x=y^y$

Comment: Ohkk sir, sorry, my bad I missed that.Thank you for pointing out Sir

Comment: You are welcome. Please use MathJax to format your equations

Comment: Will make it sure next time..